# Where to edit Wordpress widgets?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Where do I edit the content of Wordpress widgets? When I open a specific widget inside our Wordpress CMS, all I see is:

`[cl_display_thumbnail_list]`

A sample page is http://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/lawyer-profiles/bill-doogue and the section I want to edit is the lower portion with small images. I want to put them in multiple columns instead of being individually displayed in block. The problem is I don't know where to find the part where I can change class names or divs, etc.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just open notepad++ and find `cl_display_thumbnail_list` in plugin folder that you use.I can help you if I know which widget are you used.Its Generally in `function.php` or `shortcode.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

`[cl_display_thumbnail_list]` is a shortcode. Typically, shortcodes are defined in edited in a **shortcodes.php** or **functions.php** file, within a theme's root folder. However, it's also possible that a custom plugin is doing it.

You'll want to have a basic understanding about the [WordPress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) before changing anything.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I may have found where adjustments should be made (a function.php file) but the codes are far from the HTML codes I expect. I thought maybe I should just get rid of the shortcode inside the widget and replace it with fresh HTML codes. Will most likely solve the problem but I would've wanted to tackle the shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

WP uses core widgets : 
    wp-includes/widgets.php: register_widget()
core register for widgets:
WP_Widget_Factory::register ( string $widget_class )

**But some custom themes biuld a own way of widgets of shortcodes in own theme...**

For ex:  yourtheme/widgets.php or shortcode.php

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your widget code is.
There are two places from where you can find your widget.
1. `functions.php` (Within your theme folder)
2. `Plugins` folder. (If a plugin is used to create a widget)

Check both of the above folders to find your widget coding.
Make changes according to your need. 
`[cl_display_thumbnail_list]` is a shortcode, you need to learn about shortcodes before making any change. 
Follow the link below to understand shortcodes. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode